# Download image with smaller resolution (like picasa API)

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the GDrive API to download image from GDrive.
I would like to get a smaller image compare to the original one.

By example GDrive contains a photo of 2.2MB 3264 × 2448, I would like that the API can return the image in multiple resolutions (like picase is doing)

Is there any params I can set in the REST API to get this result ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive API doesn't support the feature you're looking for. The only other resolution we provide is the one for the thumbnail.

Comment: OK, Tx, it was my understanding...but would be really nice to have new parameters in the API to provide smaller images for mobile devices applications.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we'll look at what we can do.